# Integral of a product of two symmetrical functions

Tags: probability-theory, definite-integrals, symmetry

I have to calculate a rather difficult integral, and I was asking myself if there were clever ways to approach this integral. 
I have to calculate $E[X^2]$. I know that $E[X] = \frac{1}{2}$, because of symmetry in the point $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Let $f_X(x) = \alpha k(\alpha) \left(2 - e^{x-1/\alpha} - e^{-x/\alpha} \right)$,

then $E[X^2] = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} x^2 \cdot \alpha k(\alpha) \left(2 - e^{x-1/\alpha} - e^{-x/\alpha} \right)$d$x$

Note that this function is only defined between $0 \le x \le 1$.

Do I have to calculate this by brute force, or can I do something more elegant here?

Comment: Yes, I'd say brute force. Just a couple integration by parts for the exponential functions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Integrating by parts twice, one gets
$$
\int_0^1x^2e^{ax}dx=\left(\frac{2}{a^3}-\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a}\right)e^a-\frac2{a^3},\qquad a \neq0.
$$ Then one may apply it to
$$
\begin{align}
E[X^2] &=  \alpha k(\alpha)\int_{0}^{1} x^2 \cdot \left(2 - e^{x-1/\alpha} - e^{-x/\alpha} \right)dx
\\&=2 \alpha k(\alpha)\int_{0}^{1}x^2dx- \alpha k(\alpha)e^{-1/\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}x^2e^{x}dx- \alpha k(\alpha)\int_{0}^{1}x^2e^{-x/\alpha}dx.
\end{align}
$$